# arecord does not terminate, even with -d option

Tags: usb, osmc

I'm using the command line to record sound from a USB webcam, and it is almost working (sound is being recorded), however there is an issue with `arecord`: even when using the `-d` (`--duration`) option, the process does not terminate.

The command-line I'm using is the following:

```
arecord -D plughw:1,0 -f cd --duration=1
```

(I've omitted the piping to `lame`, since it is irrelevant here.)

Because the output is being written to `stdin`, I can see lots of garbage being output (as expected), and then after 1 second (or any other interval I choose), the output stops, but the process is still running. I have to Ctrl+C to terminate it.

I tried the same exact command-line (using the same webcam) on my desktop, and it works as intended: the process terminates after the specified duration. It also terminates when using other sound devices.

The issue seems to be specific to the Raspberry Pi, e.g. some driver, or `arecord` (`arecord --version` outputs `arecord: version 1.0.28 by Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>` on my Pi 3, while it is 1.1.4 on my desktop), or something else.

Is this a known issue? Is there something specific that needs to be done on the RPi to ensure that `arecord` terminates?

Comment: I had the same problem, and I fixed it by downloading older version of arecord.
Reference: http://blog.nagimov.com/alsa-utils-arecord-bug-lots-of-wav-files-ignoring-duration-parameter/